# Null value after parse json

Tags: ios, json, nsmutabledictionary

My app sends receipt to server after restore purchase. To dictionary adds two additional keys: "bundleId" (app bundle id), "UUID" (app identifierForVendor).
After approved and first run, application everything is ok (after restoring i getting all keys). When the user deleted the application and reinstall, these to keys has null value.

Fetch current appStoreReceipt:

```
   if(!self.receiptData){

    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                         appStoreReceiptURL];
self.receiptData = [NSData
            dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL] 
receipt = [self.receiptData bkrBase64EncodedString];
    }
    else{
        receipt = [self.receiptData bkrBase64EncodedString];
    }
```

Apple request:

```
if(receipt){
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *requestContents = @{
                                      @"receipt-data" : receipt,
                                      @"password" : //purchaseAppSecreatKey
                                      };
    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                          options:0
                                                            error:&error];

    if (!requestData) { /* ... Handle error ... */
    }
    // Create a POST request with the receipt data.
    NSURL *storeURL = ///iTunesVerificationURL

    NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest =
    [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
    [storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

    // Make a connection to the iTunes Store on a background queue.
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:storeRequest
     queue:operationQueue
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data,
                         NSError *connectionError) {

         if (connectionError) {
         NSLog(@"response error %@", connectionError.localizedDescription);

         } else {

             NSError *error;
             NSDictionary *jsonResponse =
             [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                              options:0
                                                error:&error] ;

             if(!error){
                //success, sending to server
             }else{
                 NSLog(@"parse error %@", error.localizedDescription);
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

Send to server code

```
NSMutableDictionary *requestBodyDictonary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:reciptDic];
[requestBodyDictonary setObject:[self bundleId] forKey:@"bundleId"];
[requestBodyDictonary setObject:[self UUID] forKey:@"uuid"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *bodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestBodyDictonary options:0 error:&error];

if(error == nil){
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                    initWithURL:url
                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                    timeoutInterval:15.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    [request setHTTPBody:bodyData];

    NSURLSession *defaultstSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [defaultstSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"complete %ld", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
    }];

    [task resume];

}else{

    NSLog(@"error parshe %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Fetched uuid and bundleid

```
   #pragma mark - User ID
-(NSString *)UUID{

    if(!_UUID){
        _UUID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"identifierForVendor_UUID"];
        if(!_UUID){
            _UUID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:_UUID forKey:@"identifierForVendor_UUID"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        }
    }

    return _UUID;
}

#pragma mark bundle id
-(NSString *)bundleId{

    if(!_bundleId){
        _bundleId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"app_BundleId"];

        if(!_bundleId){

            _bundleId = [[NSBundle mainBundle]bundleIdentifier];
            if(!_bundleId){
                _bundleId = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(CFBundleGetInfoDictionary(CFBundleGetMainBundle()),
                                                                               (const void *)(@"CFBundleIdentifier"));
            }
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_bundleId forKey:@"app_BundleId"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }

    return _bundleId;
}
```

Why my app return null after reinstall?
In sandbox mode everything is ok

Comment: What returns `null`? If it's related to `NSUserDefaults`, you must know that they are completely deleted after a re-install.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei I know that, but if value from NSUserDefaults is nil i fetch once again and store it in NSUserDefaults. In first version of app I not use NSUserDefaults but still has null

Answer (score 0):

If you delete an APP then it will clear all NSUserDefault values also, we have to use keychain to store values, it will remain same if you delete app.

use KeychainItemWrapper files to store both UDID and BundleID

download keychanItemwrapper from github

```
#import "KeychainItemWrapper.h"

then set values do Like this:

 UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

 NSString *div = [[device identifierForVendor]UUIDString];

 keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestUDID" accessGroup:nil];

 userDevice_id = [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];

    if([userDevice_id isEqualToString:@""])

    {

keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestUDID" accessGroup:nil];

        [keychain setObject:div forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];

}
```

get values from variable:

```
 keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestUDID" accessGroup:nil];

        userDevice_id = [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
```

Comment: Please see my code once again, when value from NSUserDefault is nil i use `[[NSBundle mainBundle]bundleIdentifier];` to fetch value and next store it to NSUserDefault. First version of my app not use NSUserDefault and still have null after parse son from my server.